# How to set CSRF token in angular page - OWASP CSRFGuard 3.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp

1. I have used Spring MVC to build my restful services:
   http://localhost:8088/SpringRestCSRF/rest/rest/greeting
2. I am using OWASP CSRFGuard 3.0 to protect these Restful services from CSRF.
3. When accessing the same Rest service using a simple HTML - AJAX request - CSRF token is getting set and I am getting the response:

Below code is working Fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>REST Service with CSRF Protection</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- First Get call OWASP CSRFGuard JS servlet which sets the token --> 
  <script src="http://localhost:8088/SpringRestCSRF/CsrfJavaScriptServlet"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:8088/SpringRestCSRF/rest/rest/greeting",
            type: 'POST',

        }).then(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
            $('.greeting-id').append(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p class="greeting-id">The Response is  is : </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

4. When I am trying the same thing using Angular, the token is not getting set and I am getting CSRF guard error.

Angular Code **( I am very new to Angular)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Assumption - First Get call to OWASP CSRFGuard JS servlet which sets the token --> 

<script src="http://localhost:8088/SpringRestCSRF/CsrfJavaScriptServlet"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <button ng-click="testPost(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
        <br /> Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}

        <br /> Cookie Value {{$cookies}}
    </div>

    <script>
        /*----------------*/

        var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

        app
                .controller(
                        'MyController',
                        function($scope, $http) {
                            $scope.result = "";

                            $scope.init = function() {
                                $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
                                $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
                            };

                            $scope.testPost = function() {
                                $http
                                        .post(
                                                'http://localhost:8088/SpringRestCSRF/rest/rest/greeting')
                                        .success(function(result) {
                                            $scope.result = result;
                                            $scope.myData.fromServer = data;
                                        });
                            };
                        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can someone suggest how should I set the Token in Angular.

Quote from Angular:

> While searching a solution to this problem, read the below statement.
>
> Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection XSRF is a technique by
>   which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data. Angular
>   provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR requests,
>   the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN)
>   and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only JavaScript
>   that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server can be
>   assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain. The
>   header will not be set for cross-domain requests.
>
> To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
>   JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP
>   GET request. On subsequent XHR requests the server can verify that the
>   cookie matches X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that
>   only JavaScript running on your domain could have sent the request.
>   The token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the
>   server (to prevent the JavaScript from making up its own tokens). We
>   recommend that the token is a digest of your site's authentication
>   cookie with a salt for added security.
>
> The name of the headers can be specified using the xsrfHeaderName and
>   xsrfCookieName properties of either $httpProvider.defaults at
>   config-time, $http.defaults at run-time, or the per-request config
>   object.

Answer (score 0):

now with angular2 the things has changed .. but if you still use the old version , you can use this :

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
});

app.controller ...etc
```